# Chaotic billiard with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, metapost, asymptote

I'm looking for a TikZ library that could help me to represent different shapes of chaotic billiards.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: do you want tikz to calculate the trajectories as well or do you have other means to prouduce a series of points?

Comment: ideally, Tikz should do all the work

Comment: Is there any way to parametrize the solution? It should be possible to come up with an analytically described path for the circle but how do you calculate it for other shapes?

Comment: that is the main problem, for chaotic shapes the paths are very messy, I could probably find my points using matlab and do the conversion. I was wondering if a magic tool in Tikz could have an iterative way to represent this figure

Comment: Are the curves really random? I expected them to be properly deflected from the border. That would mean the initial values (point and direction) determine the path perfectly.

Comment: The billiard shape is simple, but for example with the blue one represented up there, the ray tends to fill the entire space after several reflexions, that's what I want to illustrate. You're right, the starting point and the direction determine the path, assuming there is no error propagation.

Comment: Donut, they are rules on the propagation of a ray in the billiard, equivalent to optical geometry rules imposing angle conservation for each reflexion. The random set of points on the curve would not satisfy them.

Comment: One way of achieving what you want is explained [here](http://blancosilva.wordpress.com/latex/interaction-with-sage/):1. create the tikzpicture environment, 2. use the sagetex package to do the calculations in the CAS Sage, 3. insert the calculations into  latex commands by calling a \sagestr{output} command inside the tikzpicture environment.

Comment: great, thanks ! I will take a look at sagetex

Comment: (–1) What is chaotic billard? (The images you posted do not look chaotic.) How are these shapes defined? What happens here? What are the rules? What is the math behind it? What is the input? — While TikZ can calculate the direction of a curve (straight, circular, ellipsoid, Bézier) on any point, this information is pretty much forgotten after the drawing. One could help with coordinates placed along the path and the `intersections` library but this will need tremendous work for a chaotic billard table. Rectangles, ellipses, rounded rectangles and regular polygons: easier.

Comment: A chaotic billiard is a billiard where a random ray tends to fill the entire space after several bounces (like the rounded rectangle), unlike the regular billiard where there will remain blank spaces (like the circular billiard). It's usually simple to get chaos and reach an ergodic propagation, you can mix a rectangular shape with a convex one, like for example the Sinai billiard that Alex made in his edit. Thus, for tiny modifications of the initial conditions, you can get very different setups

Comment: If you do not have the coordinate (the hits) beforehand, TikZ and its `intersections` library is not the tool for this task. It lacks the precision: For a circle of radius of 2 and a starting point of `(45:2)` and the direction `-90`, the [result after 20 hit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BIi1C.png) shows that the hits are not as expected all at `(n*90+45:2)` (for all integer `n`s). The [result for 200 hits](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OYhXz.png) is even worse. Note that the inner empty region is shifting downwards.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is another nice one for [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/), which can calculate intersections and directions of paths easily:

[image: circle billiard]

[image: stadium billiard]

Here's the code for the stadium billiard:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}[width=10cm,height=10cm]
import graph;

size(200);

// circle billiard
// path bill = Circle((0,0),90.0);
// real phi = 2*pi*0.23456;

// stadium billiard
path bill = (-50,-50)--(50,-50)--arc((50,0), 50, -90, 90)
  --(50,50)--(-50,50)--arc((-50,0), 50, 90, 270)--cycle;
real phi = 2*pi*0.123456;


draw(bill);


pair s = (20,20), db, dt = exp(I*phi), e = s+200*dt;
path traj = s--e;
real [] c;


for(int i=0; i<50; ++i) {

  c = intersect(bill, traj);
  e = point(traj, c[1]);
  db = dir(bill, c[0]);

  draw(s--e,red);
  dot(e,blue);

  dt = -dt + 2*dot(dt,db)*db;

  s = e;
  e = s + 200*dt;

  traj = (s+dt)--e;
}
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

To get the circle, uncomment the lines

```
// path bill = Circle((0,0),90.0);
// real phi = 2*pi*0.23456;
```

and comment out the billiard path

```
path bill = (-50,-50)--(50,-50)--arc((50,0), 50, -90, 90)
  --(50,50)--(-50,50)--arc((-50,0), 50, 90, 270)--cycle;
real phi = 2*pi*0.123456;
```

**EDIT:** This question is so much fun, I had to do the Sinai billiard as well:

[image]

The code has only a few more lines:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}[width=10cm,height=10cm]
import graph;

size(200);

// Sinai billiard
path bill = (-90,-90)--(90,-90)--(90,90)--(-90,90)--cycle;
path inner = reverse(Circle((0,0),30.0));
real phi = 2*pi*0.05;

filldraw(bill^^inner,lightgray,black);


pair s = (30,30), db, dt = exp(I*phi), e = s+200*dt;
path traj = s--e;
real [] co;
real [][] ci;


for(int i=0; i<80; ++i) {

  co = intersect(traj, bill);
  ci = intersections(traj, inner);

  if(ci.length > 0) {
    e = point(traj, ci[0][0]);
    db = dir(inner, ci[0][1]);
  } else {
    e = point(traj, co[0]);
    db = dir(bill, co[1]);
  }

  draw(s--e,red);
  dot(e,blue);

  dt = -dt + 2*dot(dt,db)*db;

  s = e;
  e = s + 200*dt;

  traj = (s+dt)--e;
}
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems also very simple to use, thanks a lot !

Comment: @Thomas Yes, basically you can use any closed path that you can build with Bezier curves...

Comment: You sir, made my day :)

Comment: The Sinai billiard makes me a mistake during the Asymptote compilation : "rading array of length 2 with out-of-bounds index 4"

Comment: The problem appears when the ray intersects the circle.

Comment: @Thomas The wrong index was in `ci[0][4]`, which should be `ci[0][1]`. Maybe the online editor mixed it up with the references for the figure? My original code doesn't have the 4. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @ Alex Thanks for all the work you've made here. I still have a problem of index out of boundaries for large values of i, like if there was no intersection. EDIT : solved using "e = s+300*dt"

Comment: @Thomas Seem's to occur at i=309, where the trajectory directly hits a corner and gets the reflection wrong. Maybe we need to handle this case separately...

Comment: with "e = s+300*dt" I don't have this problem anymore, or we just can change the initial conditions.

Comment: @Thomas I see, we should normalize `dt`...

Comment: How about an arbitrary closed curve?

Answer (score 12):

For comparison, here is a translation of Alex's code to Metapost.

```
\starttext
\startMPpage[offset=2mm]

u := 1mm;
phi := 0.12345;

path billiard, ball, trajectory;
pair dt, hit, location, awayPoint, tangent; 

% stadium billiard
billiard = (-50u,-50u)--( 50u,-50u) {right} .. {left}  (50u, 50u) 
        -- (-50u, 50u)--(-50u, 50u) {left}  .. {right} cycle;

ball := fullcircle scaled 3mm;

draw billiard;

location := (20u, 20u);
dt := dir(phi);

for i = 0 upto 50 :
  awayPoint := location + 200u*dt ;
  trajectory := (location+dt) -- awayPoint;

  save timeBilliard, timeBall;
  (timeBilliard, timeBall) = billiard intersectiontimes trajectory;

  hit := point timeBilliard of billiard;
  draw location -- hit withcolor red;
  fill ball shifted hit withcolor blue;

  tangent := direction timeBilliard of billiard;
  % The result of direction has arbitrary magnitude. Normalize it;
  tangent := tangent/abs(tangent);

  dt := -dt + 2*(dt dotprod tangent)*tangent;
  location  := hit;

endfor

\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

Increasing the amount of reflections to 500 gives:

[image]

and increasing it to 2000 gives:

[image]

which shows space filling.

If however one starts with a circle, then 2000 collisions gives:

[image]

A fun option is to add randomization to the reflection: After normalizing the tangent add

```
  % Randomize the tangent
  tangent := tangent randomized 0.3;
  % Renormalize the result
  tangent := tangent/abs(tangent);
```

which gives:

[image]

With this randomization, if you start with a circle, you get space filling (after 2000 collisions):

[image]

Comment: Cool. But still no tikz solution ;-)

Comment: Nevermind, that's also a cool and simple solution :)

Comment: Your edit with 2000 reflexions illustrates perfectly the chaotic properties of different  shapes of billiard !